# MockWebServer not wait N seconds to return stub response

Tags: android, mockwebserver

Android Espresso's test:

**first version**

```
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer

private lateinit var mockServer: MockWebServer

   @Rule
   @JvmField
   var tradersIntentTestRule = IntentsTestRule(TradersActivity::class.java, false, false)

@Before
    fun setup() {
        mockServer = MockWebServer()
        mockServer.start(8081)
        Debug.d(TAG, "setup_START")

}


@Test
    fun testMockServer() {
        Debug.d(TAG, "testMockServer_start")
        mockServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(200)
                .setBodyDelay(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .setBody(FileUtil.getStringFromFile(context, randomTraderStubName.stubName)));
        Debug.d(TAG, "testMockServer_finish")
    }


    @After
    @Throws
    fun tearDown() {
        mockServer.shutdown()
}
```

Here result logcat:

```
05-31 18:10:52.327 D/com.myproject.activity.TradersActivityTest(10312): testMockServer_start
05-31 18:10:52.371 D/com.myproject.activity.TradersActivityTest(10312): testMockServer_finish
```

as you can see the text "`testMockServer_finish`" show **immediately**. Not wait 10 seconds.

**second version:**

```
 @Test
    fun testMockServer() {
        Debug.d(TAG, "testMockServer_start")
        tradersIntentTestRule.finishActivity()
        mockServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(200)
                .setBodyDelay(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .setBody(FileUtil.getStringFromFile(context, randomTraderStubName.stubName)));
        tradersIntentTestRule.launchActivity(Intent())
        Debug.d(TAG, "testMockServer_finish")
}
```

result logcat:

```
05-31 18:14:54.103 D/com.myproject.android.activity.TradersActivityTest(11689): testMockServer_start
05-31 18:15:04.322 D/com.myproject.android.activity.TradersActivityTest(11689): testMockServer_finish
```

and now as you can see the text "`testMockServer_finish`" show **after 10 seconds**

Why on first version not wait 10 seconds?